# how can i get the volume of the current sound?

Tags: volume

I want crate an app that can show the wave of a mp3, just like the Microsoft Media Player (visualizations ->Bars and waves ->ocean mist).
But how can I get the volume of every second?
is there any function can get the volume?
C, C++, C# all kinds of code will do!

[image]

Comment: Lets say every sample is represented by an 8-bit unsigned integer. Then zero is quiet and 255 is the loudest. That's the simplified version of how it works.

Comment: "c,c++,c# all kinds of code will do!". No, no, and no. Are you writing a music player? If so, you should know how to get the volume already, and you probably want code in the language you are already using. Pick one. If not, and you want an app to show the current sound playing in your system you will probably need to pick a platform, as this is highly dependent on that.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you have access to the sample buffer, you will often want either the peak (absolute) value in the range representing 1 second or the RMS (Root Mean Square) value in the 1 second range of samples.